# How will the X ray diffraction pattern change if the crystal changes its lattice structure

Tags: x-ray-diffraction

(I asked this question on another community without getting much help there,I hence post it here as it may be more of a chemistry question. I apologize if my question has an obvious answer, I'm only a beginner)

A text says:
`An X - ray diffraction experiment is carried out on a crystalline solid having  FCC structure at room temperature. The solid undergoes a phase transformation on  cooling and shows orthorhombic structure with small decrease in its unit cell  lengths as compared to the FCC unit cell lengths. As a result the 311 line of the XRD pattern corresponding to the FCC system will split into a triplet`

**Now this is what i could think about it:**
We know that the interplanar distance for an orthorhombic lattice is given as $$
d=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{h^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{k^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{l^{2}}{c^{2}}}}
$$ and using Bragg's law we can find the angle at which constructive interference occurs as $$
\sin \theta=\frac{\lambda}{2 d}=\frac{\lambda}{2} \sqrt{\frac{k^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{k^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{l^{2}}{c^{2}}}$$
using the values of$${h k l}$$$$={3 1 1}$$ we obtain the diffraction angle which is unique as given by the above equation. Beyond this I cannot understand what to do,how does any splitting occur, what am I missing.

Comment: So $a,b,c$ are different in orthorhombic vs an fcc cell, right?

Comment: I  believe  that's correct.

Comment: So what does that mean for the 311?

Comment: please check your second equation and rewrite it as it is not consistent with the first.

Comment: See, there are 311, 131, and 113. In FCC, they are all the same. In orthorhombic, no longer so. That's the splitting.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin, thank you. Isn't it that the text should have put the indices inside angular brackets like <3 1 1> to indicate that it meant a family of directions?

Comment: Maybe, but we got used to understand it anyway.

Comment: @Ivan, for beginners like me?

Comment: You'll get used to it, too. Then again, how would a beginner know the meaning of angular brackets (which is not universal, mind you)?

Comment: Oh! I thought it was universal. Thanks again.